# How do I determine the type of the MySQL Checksum column?

Tags: mysql, checksum, sqldatatypes

I want to run a `CHECKSUM TABLE <sometable>` to determine whether a table is changing over time. If not changing, then it is likely that something is broken in my software and I have to check what could be in the way.

Now, how do I determine the type of the Checksum column? There is what I get when I run the command:

```
mysql> CHECKSUM TABLE snaplist.journal;
+------------------+-----------+
| Table            | Checksum  |
+------------------+-----------+
| snaplist.journal | 740533432 |
+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

It looks like it could be `uint32_t`, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to tell exactly what is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a few dozen.  It sure looks like `INT UNSIGNED` would work.

Caution:  If you have 2K tables (or 2K variations in the table), there is a 1 in 2K chance of a false match.

Comment: Right, I'm not so much questioning the checksum itself, but the column type. I understand that the checksum has its limits. What I tried and couldn't do is a `DESCRIBE ...` or something of the sort so we can actually see the type, however, it is very likely that this table output is generated on the fly so they don't give you access to a description of the table. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - True; there is no way to ask MySQL what the output type is of `CHECKSUM TABLE`, nor some other things.